# Set request body variables using Google Drive Java SDK

Tags: java, google-drive-api

I am using the Google Drive Java SDK to [patch a file in Drive](https://developers.google.com/drive/v2/reference/files/patch). The API reference mentions a set of variables that can be sent as JSON within the request body.

While I can use

```
Files.Patch patchRequest = service.files().patch(fileId, file);
```

to get a request object and set the actual **parameters** specified in the API reference through various set methods, I can't find a method to set the actual **body** of the request.

I was looking at the

```
 com.google.api.client.util.GenericData.setUnknownKeys(Map<String, Object> unknownFields)
```

method so that I can deserialize some JSON as a HashMap and pass it, but it doesn't seem to work.

Is there a specific method in the SDK that I can use to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer for this. In order to set request body parameters, the Google Drive SDK provides a map on each request object. So calling

`Files.Patch patchRequest = service.files().patch(fileId, file);
 patchRequest.set("key", "value");`

will set request body parameters for the request.